# Send a file&data from android client (Android device) to C# server (on PC) via USB Cable

Tags: c#, android

I am looking into writing an application for personal use, 
where I want to send data or a file from the android client (on android phone) to the C# server application (on my computer- Windows 7), hopefully through USB cable. 
I wrote the C# server and the android client. They can communicate via on the same LAN, but it failed through USB-Cable.
How I would go about setting up this communication? 
Can someone give the sample or code for me ?? Thank you!

Comment: have you tried samba share? http://techiesandeep.com/#/

Comment: No... if I set android phone as server and C# as client. They can communicate through "adb forward tcp:12580 tcp:10086"  Then exchange them, can not work.